# Trying to show fetched firebase data on profile view SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I'm trying to show the data I fetched from my Firebase database. I tried creating `@State` var variables and add them to my function but it didn't work. I tried printing my function output in a button to print it to console and it works. I just don't know how to show them in my view my code

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ProfileView: View {    
    var body: some View {    
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                profilef()
            }) {
                Text("hello")
            }

            HStack {
                Button(action: {    

                    try! Auth.auth().signOut()    
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")

                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)    
                }) {
                    Text("Logout")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func profilef() {    
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("UserInfo").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]

            let name = value?["fullName"] as? String ?? ""
            print(name)

            // ...
        }) { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a @State variable, which contains the name. If your function changes that variable, your view will updates.

struct profile: View {

```
@State var name : String = ""

var body: some View {

    Text("Hello " + self.name)
```

And then in your function, instead of printing you will assign it to your state.

```
let name = value?["fullName"] as? String ?? ""
print(name)
self.name = name
```

That should work. I do not have an example with Firebase at the moment, so I can not test it. If it is not working, please describe the behavior.

Comment: thanks for the reply! however I get this error Use of unresolved identifier 'self'. also in my tab view which I use for navigating between views I get Missing parameter in call right after I add the @State Variable

Comment: Make sure the function is inside the struct. If you add @State vat name : String = ”” with a default value, you shouldn’t get an error in the other view

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `@State` property `profileName` and assigning it in the network request function will work after tapping the `Button`.

```
//  ProfileView.swift
//
//
//  Created by Shahin Bararesh on 2020-09-07.
//

import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ProfileView: View {

    @State var profileName: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                profilef()
            }) {
                Text(profileName)
            }

            HStack {
                Button(action: {

                    try! Auth.auth().signOut()

                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")

                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)

                }) {
                    Text("Logout")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func profilef() {

        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("UserInfo").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]

            let name = value?["fullName"] as? String ?? ""

            self.profileName = name

            // ...
        }) { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get this Use of unresolved identifier 'self'